# How do I add a file during Installation with Wix Toolset 4?

Tags: wix, wix4

So I am installing some certificates for a user and I want to add a different .PFX file everytime; I want the admin that is installing this to select the .PFX file manually every time during installation, is there an easy way to do this using Wix or do I need a very complicated custom action?

I searched a lot and found many answers that contained very complicated coding that seems way too crazy for what a lot of installers seem to have, so I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [iis:Certificate element](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/iis/certificate/) supports your scenario. The CertificatePath attribute can be a formatted value that resolves to the path of the certificate you want installed. Something a bit like:

```xml
<Component ...>
  <iis:Certificate CertificatePath="[PropertyWithPathToCert]" .../>
  ...
```

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you for the quick answer! So basically I can link a property to a control in the UI that can browse for a file, right? Is there such a control? I managed to figure out I can have an Edit field in the UI and link it to the property which would be the password for the PFX file (that the admin inputs while installing), but I can't seem to find a browseforfile Ui Control! Appreciate your work!!!!! `<Control Id="DBSText" Type="Edit" X="20" Y="72" Width="290" Height="18"
 Property="PFXSIFRA" />
</Dialog>`

Comment: You are on the right path. Your questions are good questions, but not good comments. :)

Comment: You know I'm going to figure it out :D! Hurry up with Dojo season 2, your fans miss the videos bruv! 

Once I figure it out I will post the solution here, I've got something cooking for tomorrow, thank you for your initial answer, I realized I can just write the name of the file and it's location in an edit field and the CertificatePath will pick up the desired file but I also want it to look pretty, I think i Can use the BrowseDlg for that but I will test some more tomorrow.

Comment: Okay so to everybody wondering the same thing as me there is no file select module in Wix, the Browse UI is only able to select the folder and then list that location as a property that it can pass to the CertificatePath attribute, which works, but it would definitely be epic if we had a file select module

Comment: You'll want to take it up with the Windows Installer team at Microsoft. They decide which controls are supported in the internal UI.